# How do I pass value from modal box back to the page in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

Is it possible to pass a value back to a page from a modal popup?
Any input would be greatly appreciated. I don't need you to type code for me just point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Are you talking about [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)? If so, they're loaded in the same DOM as your page. You can manipulate the entire page from scripts loaded in the modal.

Comment: yeah thanks ..it wasnt working and now it works odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these should help:

http://bootstrap2modaldemo.scripting.com/#

http://askdialogdemo.scripting.com/#

http://modalwithpopup.blorkmark.com/

(View source <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to see the code)

Code looks like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#windowTitleDialog').bind('show', function () {
            document.getElementById ("xlInput").value = document.title;
        });
    });
    function closeDialog () {
        $('#windowTitleDialog').modal('hide'); 
    };
    function okClicked () {
        document.title = document.getElementById ("xlInput").value;
    closeDialog ();
    };
</script>
```